# LINQ: get city name from foreign table address

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Restaurant and Location tables. Location table has foreign key LocationId stored in Restaurant table. I want to select city name from location table, while getting some information from Restaurant table too. How can I retrieve it using C#.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Yes but get errors, and nothing is working. I am not an expert in LINQ, but still have good understanding.

Comment: show us what you have tried please. optimally, you give all the things we need to reproduce, for example SQL statements to create the tables and fill with example data, and the code you tried to do what you explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cityNameAndSomeRestaurantStuff = from r in Db.Restaurants
                                     join l in Db.Locations
                                     on r.LocationId equals l.LocationId
                                     select new { l.CityName, r.SomeProperty };
```

Note that the result will be an `IQueryable`, so if you want it materialised, call `.ToList()` or some similar extension